# On a Netty server, how to create outbound connections then keep using them just like incoming connections?

Tags: netty

I'm working on a system where several servers need to connect to each other and exchange data. I would like to create a server socket in each server, accept new incoming connections, but at the same time initiate some outbound connections to other servers.

Once a connection is established, be that inbound or outbound, I would expect to use it with no distinction on who was the initiator. TCP connections are symmetrical, after all, once established...

Is there a way to do this with Netty? [I'm new to it...] Looking at ServerBootstrap, I don't see how can I open an outbound connection and "attach" it so that the handler I specify in the ServerBootstrap serves for all connections.

Of course I could open only outgoing connections to all servers, but I would find it more elegant to only have one connection between each two servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider an additional bootstrap?:

```
Bootstrap outboundBootstrap = new Bootstrap();
outboundBootstrap.group(workerGroup)
            .channel(EpollSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new MyInit());
```

Then to open connection:

```
InetSocketAddress address =..;ChannelFuture future = outboundBootstrap.connect(address);
```